# sort/arrange on date in dashboard

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, pivot, shinydashboard

Im trying to make a dashboard, in which the grouper variable makes it possible to make a pivot table on different variables. One of the grouping variables is year_month (jaar_maand) while the others are categorical. If i make the plot, the order of of the months is really weird, 2019-02, then 2019-04, 2019-07, how can i fix this order to 2019-01, 2019-02, 2019-03 etc.

Kind regards,

Steffie

```
### Data ###  
## Group_by Filter Data
  output$groups1 <- renderUI({
    df_ <- mydata_()
    selectInput(inputId = "grouper1", label = "Group variable", choices = c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5","var6", "jaar_maand"), selected = "var1")
  })


  mydata_ <- reactive({
    data_ <- df2  # 
    data_
  })
 
  summary_data_ <- reactive({
    req(input$grouper1)
    mydata_() %>%
      filter(Date >= input$dateRange1[1] & Date <= input$dateRange1[2]) %>%
      dplyr::group_by(!!!rlang::syms(input$grouper1), var10) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(aantal = n()) %>%
      dplyr::arrange(!!!rlang::syms(input$grouper)) 
    
  })
  # staafdiagram 
  output$barPlot1 <- renderHighchart({
    data_ <- summary_data_()
    hchart(data_, "column", hcaes(x = (!!input$grouper1) , y = aantal , group = var10)) %>% # --> de plot zelf komt in het output deel van de UI
      hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"))
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide us with a full reproducible example.

Comment: Like above - please, share all the packages you are using and all the code needed to run your chart - then we will be able to look at it and test it. Recently, I have seen a similar question - in my environment the labels were OK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056418/x-axis-year-graph-bad-display

Answer (score 0):

From my experience these problems normally occur if you don't have your categoricals as factors.

Can't really tell where to put what from your code - but my suggestion is turning jaar-maand into a factor, so that the levels order indicate the plot order.

Answer (score 0):

Like the above comment - please, share all the packages you are using and all the code needed to run your chart - then we will be able to look at it and test it.

Recently, I have seen a similar question - in my environment the labels were OK: [x axis year graph bad display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056418/x-axis-year-graph-bad-display)

You can always define your categories rigidly: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories
Or you can even take the current strings, parse them to numbers, sort, and then update sorted categories. It requires some JavaScript code injected to R using `JS("...")` method, but it should be still easy.